# Алгоритм определения столкновения с объектом

Tags: java, алгоритм

Дело в следующем: пишу арканоид по проекту в институте. Задачей сейчас стоит организация алгоритма столкновения шарика с блоками. Т.е. нужно определять, когда он с ними сталкивается, чтобы менять направление шарика.
Что я делал? Я попробовал написать у класса Block (кирпичики на скрине) метод touchBounds, который определял, какую грань блока шарик задел и в зависимости от этого возвращает целое от 0 до 3. Вызывает сомнения по поводу оптимизации. Так как каждые 1000 / 60 миллисекунд мне нужно проделывать данную операцию со всеми имеющимися блоками. Так как я в этом деле профан, прошу совета, может кто знает каким образом обычно обрабатываются данные ситуации в программировании?[image: Скрин]

Код:

```
public int touchBounds( int[][] a, int inc ) {
    int xC = ( a[0][0] + a[1][0] ) / 2;
    int yC = ( a[0][1] + a[2][1] ) / 2;
    if ( between( yC, offset[0][1] - ( inc + 1 ), offset[0][1] ) && between( xC, offset[0][0], offset[1][0] ) ) {
        return 0;
    } else if ( between( yC, offset[0][1], offset[2][1] ) && between( xC, offset[1][0], offset[1][0] + ( inc + 1 ) ) ) {
        return 1;
    } else if ( between( yC, offset[2][1], offset[2][1] + ( inc + 1 ) ) && between( xC, offset[0][0], offset[1][0] ) ) {
        return 2;
    } else if ( between( yC, offset[0][1], offset[2][1] ) && between( xC, offset[0][0] - ( inc + 1 ), offset[0][0] ) ) {
        return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}
private boolean between( int a, int b, int c ) {
    if ( a >= b && a <= c ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

, где inc - определяется дифферент положения шарика,
  int[][] a - offset шарика,
  xC - центр шарика по X,
  xY - центр шарика по Y

Comment: Написал тут длинный комментарий попал в ограничение по символам, потом решил его удалить и отправить в гугл читать по теме **collision detection**, ибо в вашем "алгоритме" нет ничего о поиске пересечений двух линий. Шарик не статичный и имеет скорость, как только скорость превысит радиус шарика - метод поиска пересечения которым вы пользуетесь начнет давать сбои, поэтому вам надо пересечение двух линий искать....
**По оптимизации** - Дробите экран на части и проверяйте пересечения только с теми блоками которые находятся в одной части с шариком, это самое первое что стоит оптимизировать.

Answer (score 1):

До столкновения шарик летит по прямой (или по какой-то другой - обычно предсказуемой -траектории). Поэтому можно при начале движения **один раз** найти, с каким кирпичом он столкнется первым, в какое время, и до этого времени только перерисовывать шарик в новых координатах.

Когда происходит столкновение, конфигурация может поменяться, и после отскока нужно пересчитать, с каким следующим будет столкновение.

Думаю, что при количестве кирпичей, реальном для арканоида (десятки) - не стоит использовать сложные структуры данных, позволяющие ограничить проверки - простого перебора будет достаточно.

Comment: Плюсик вам от меня, это вторая оптимизация, но (незнаю полного ТЗ "игры") может не сработать если "блоки" имеют движение свое собственное которое так же будет учитывать коллизии между ними... и еще у автора коллизии считаются не верно изначально =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Да, я думал о движении блоков, но автор ничего не упоминал об этом.